# What is the best practice if we need to create a 'grid' of anchors for indoor navigation?

Tags: augmented-reality, azure-spatial-anchors

['Best practice' of ASA](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6oPF.png)

[Windows-Mixed-Reality-Design-Core concepts-Spatial anchors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/mixed-reality/design/spatial-anchors)

According to the 'best practice' above, it is not recommented to create a 'grid' of anchors. To my understanding this is because the sensor drift would make the 'anchor map' distorted (e.g. when you create one anchor and then walk a few meters away and place another anchor.)

My question here is What is the best practice if we really need to deploy many anchors in a building (for positioning for indoor navigation purpose). For example, is it a good idea to increase the density of anchors? Is it a good practice that "creating anchor A -> save it -> locate anchor A -> move little like 1 meter -> create anchor B -> save it"? Would that be helpful(as the move is little, so sensor drift should be little).

Answer (score 0):

If this is a Unity project, you can look into World Locking Tools for Unity.  It's effectively creating those many anchors under the covers.

https://github.com/microsoft/MixedReality-WorldLockingTools-Unity

To combine it with ASA, there are Space Pins.  I don't know of a full blown sample combining ASA and WLT though.

https://microsoft.github.io/MixedReality-WorldLockingTools-Unity/DocGen/Documentation/Concepts/Advanced/SpacePins.html

Comment: Thank you! It would be interesting to see the combination of ASA and WLT